# is there any way to pass parameter as default value for a parameter in datastage?

Tags: parameters, datastage

I am trying to pass a query as parameter(default value) in sequence job , the query contains additional parameters which is not taking the values in the job run. are there any other ways to do it?

Thanks,
Jothi

Comment: Explain your problem in more detail and add code samples - do not let us guess please

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from a sequence job in normal operations.